# CDF of a Tweedie Distribution

Tags: r, cumulative-distribution-function, quantiles, tweedie-distribution

The R package [tweedie](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tweedie/index.html) provides a way to estiamate the density and CDF of Tweedie distribution (using `dtweedie` and `ptweedie`, respectively). I'm more interested in the `dtweedie.series` and `ptweedie.series` functions as they are (I think) simpler to interpret. I've found the author's paper [Dunn & Smyth, Series evaluation of Tweedie exponential dispersion densities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220286602_Series_evaluation_of_Tweedie_exponential_dispersion_densities?enrichId=rgreq-302aa8b8b2cf57e57fd9bd72d4817b47-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyMDI4NjYwMjtBUzo5OTM1ODE5NjM3MTQ2NUAxNDAwNzAwMjQ5NDQx&el=1_x_2) that discusses `dtweedie.series` function (for density), but I can't seem to figure out what the `ptweedie.series` (for the CDF).

Is there any clue to how the CDF of a Tweedie is calculated? What about the inverse CDF?